# auth0 get all users from angular 2

Tags: angular, jwt, auth0

I need to get all users from auth0 (https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users) from anguler2. 
this what i tried. I know i have to add the access token somewhere. Please point me to a correct direction.

```js
var headers: any = {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     };

     this.authHttp.get('https://nsrevo.au.auth0.com/api/v2/users?search_engine=v2', { headers: headers})
         .map(response => response.json())
         .subscribe(
             response => {
                 console.log(response);
             },
             error => alert(error.json().message)
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your headers you need to add the Authorization Bearer header with the Management APIv2 [token](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens) (Which you should get from a server-side script securely) to successfully call this API:

```
Authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_TOKEN
```

Also make sure the Management APIv2 token you get, has the minimum scopes required for your Application. In this case the scope should be `read:users` and `read:users read:user_idp_tokens` as said in the API [docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users).